# Node.js - How to delete an entry when Ok is clicked in Confirmation Box

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to delete the entry which is in table row when we click Ok in confirmation box.

I am able to show confirmation box but don't know how to delete the table row.

My view page (Jade Template),

```
extends layout

block content
  h1(style='text-align:center')= title
  button(type='submit', onClick='add()') Add a Material
  script.
    function add() {
      window.location.href = '/addpage'
    }
    function edit() {
      window.location.href = '/editpage'
    }
    function remove() {
      let txt;
      if(confirm('Are you sure to delete?')){
        txt = 'Pressed Ok';
      } else {
        txt = 'Pressed Cancel';
      }
    }
  br
  br
  -var product = data
  div
  table.table.table-hover(border='1', style='width:100%', id='content')
    tr
        th Sl.No
        th Plant
        th Material
        th Currency
        th Rate
        th Price_Unit
        th Cond_Unit
        th Customer
        th Portal_User
        th Options
    tbody
      each value in product
        tr
          td(style='text-align:center')
          td(style='text-align:center', name='p_plant')= value.PLANT
          td(style='text-align:left', name='p_material')= value.MATERIAL
          td(style='text-align:left', name='p_currency')= value.CURRENCY
          td(style='text-align:right', name='p_rate')= value.RATE
          td(style='text-align:center', name='p_price_unit')= value.PRICE_UNIT
          td(style='text-align:left', name='p_cond_unit')= value.COND_UNIT
          td(style='text-align:left', name='p_customer')= value.CUSTOMER
          td(style='text-align:left', name='p_portal_user')= value.PORTAL_USER
          td(style='text-align:left')
            ul
              a.btn.btn-default(href='/editpage/'+value.PLANT+'/'+value.MATERIAL+'/'+value.CUSTOMER+'/'+value.RATE+'/'+value.CURRENCY+'/'+value.PRICE_UNIT+'/'+value.COND_UNIT+'/'+value.PORTAL_USER) Edit
              br
              br
              //- a.btn.btn-default(href='/removepage/'+value.PLANT+'/'+value.MATERIAL+'/'+value.CUSTOMER+'/'+value.RATE+'/'+value.CURRENCY+'/'+value.PRICE_UNIT+'/'+value.COND_UNIT+'/'+value.PORTAL_USER) Delete
              a.btn.btn-default(href='', onClick='remove()') Delete
```

Controller for View page,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sapview = require('../sap/crud');

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const listdata = await sapview.listall();
  const pricedata = listdata.T_PRICE;
  res.render('viewpage', {title: 'Products', data: pricedata})
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello", req.body);
  client.connect(() => {
    console.log('Connecting');
    client.invoke("ZSD_CP_PRICE_DELETE", 
    {P_PLANT: req.body.P_PLANT, 
    P_MATERIAL: req.body.P_MATERIAL, 
    P_CUSTOMER: req.body.P_CUSTOMER
    },
    (err, result) => {
      console.log('Invoking')
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return err;
      }
      console.log(result);
    });
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any help on how to pass the table row data when Ok button is clicked will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the remove function you can pass the id or whatever you wants which will help you to identify the row, for eg. remove(id). And when the user clicks on Ok you can call the route using ajax function and pass the id(or whatever you choose).